# Scale position points in a circle.Look like normal scaling

Tags: vector, geometry, trigonometry

I have an Art degree, no math involved, so sometimes when doing 3D graphics and envisioning problems, it's hard to search for solutions over the internet since I don't have good pointers for search terms.
I'm sure this is a trivial problem with a proper name/solution. Basically I just want to grab P and scale its position vector so it matches P', a position on a version scaled by 0.5 on the y axis.

[image of the problem](http://i.imgur.com/PJNi3t7.png/)

My idea is to apply the same rationale to all three axis, even though I only need to do it on 2, right now.

Thanks in advance.

NOTE: I'm a visual person, if you're going into explanations more than just sharing links, please don't bomb me with long or cryptic functions :D Thanks

Comment: The [post on Math SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1146128/35416) seems more appropriate. Please [don't cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71938/188688) your questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics not programming, and has already been posted in the Math SE forum as well.

Comment: Well I'm actually applying it in a 3D application, so when I got formulas answers didn't help much, but whatever it's solved.

[link](http://screencast.com/t/UsxR4l3H2O) 

[link](http://screencast.com/t/MZKoW2bZYl3)

True about the crossing, soz about that.

Answer (score 0):

Build perpendiculars from P' to X axis and denote the intersection with X axis as C' and the intersection with circle as D' as shown in the following picture:

[image]

Then we have

|OC'| = L*cos(A) where A is the angle C'OP' and L= |OP'|

|C'P'| = 0.5*|C'D'|=L*sin(A)

We also have |OC'|^2 + |C'D'|^2 = 1, so we can solve for L as

L = 1/sqrt(cosA*cosA + 4*sinA*sinA)

Answer (score 0):

By the equation of the ellipse,

```
x'² + 4y'² = 1
```

and by the alignment of P and P',

```
x'/x = y'/y
```

The solution is

```
 x' = x / d
 y' = y / d
```

where `d= √(x² + 4y²)`.